# How can in access to my fields of Schema?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

i"ve been making some test with PyTest, one of them includes testing the schema i receive an its fields, my schema looks like:

```
class MvnoaBase(BaseModel):
    """
    Shared properties for mvnoa schema
    """
    name: str = Field(min_length=1, max_length=100)
    is_active: bool
```

i tried to access through model_fields:

```
def test_validate_length_create_mvnoa_schema(client: TestClient, mvnoa_in, expected_code):
    mvnoa_in = schemas.MVNOACreate(name=mvnoa_in['name'],
                                   is_active=mvnoa_in['is_active'])
    mvnoa_db = client.post('api/v1/mvnoa/', json=mvnoa_in.model_dump())
    fields = schemas.MVNOACreate.model_fields
    assert len(mvnoa_in['name']) <= fields['name'].metadata[1].max_length
```

But printing fields give this dict, is there another way to do it?

```
{'name': FieldInfo(annotation=str, required=True, metadata=[MinLen(min_length=1), MaxLen(max_length=100)]), 'is_active': FieldInfo(annotation=bool, required=True)}
```

Comment: What's the error/issue with the test you've written? (since you're accessing it as a dict.) I'd also like to note that I'm not sure if validating that the schema matches what you've defined is a relevant test _for your application_. It's a relevant test in FastAPI and would already be tested there, so you'd just be writing tests that are already covered by the library you're using.

Comment: That test is written because of my work environment doesn't got a clear standard for code writing. Some of the output from the current routes are in fact just lists, dicts, some another are models or schemas, a mix of them. That why i wanna test the response type.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.